# how to programmatically screen lock set from SWIPE to NONE for device specific

Tags: android, screen-lock

I would like to set screen lock from SWIPE to NONE for device specific.
Once i set and after it also show in setting also.

Comment: Did you manage to do that programmatically?

Comment: Still i didn't manage, but i want to do whole task programmatically.

Comment: I don't think you can set the lock screen mode to NONE if the current value is SWIPE. But you will reset the password if you call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#resetPassword(java.lang.String, int) with an empty string as the first parameter

Answer (score 1):

For Android 7.1, it works for me with below changes

def_lockscreen_disabled changed to 'true' in below file

> > frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml

Answer (score 0):

adb shell locksettings set-disabled true